# Removing a primary key but keeping foreign key?

Tags: sql-server

Before anyone says this is a duplicate question and down-votes: I know how to solve the issue but I would like the advice on which is the best way to go about it.

I have made a booking system, where employees can create bookings. The employees table has a primary key of their clock number, this is a foreign key in the bookings table because employees can only delete their own bookings unless they are an administrator.

Now the problem occurs when I want to remove an employee, but they have made 1 or more bookings in the system, obviously as I'm deleting the 'parent' the 'child' will want to be removed as well but I need to keep the entire history of bookings.

The solutions I have is to remove the foreign key constraint in the bookings table, so there is still a clock number but not a foreign key. Or to set something up with ON CASCADE NULL feature?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees](
    [ClockNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Forename] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Surname] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Department] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsAdmin] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Password] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ClockNo] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bookings](
    [InvoiceNo] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [ClockNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [GateNo] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [TruckNo] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Seal] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [ContainerNo] [varchar](40) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Bookings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InvoiceNo] ASC,
    [GateNo] ASC,
    [StartTime] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If there is a way without doing any of these things that would be great, as I would like the clock number to stay even if the employee has been removed so we can see who had made the booking, even if they no longer work for us

Comment: Asking *"What is the best way"* is also off topic though; as it generates opinionated answers. This sounds like you shouldn't be deleting rows, though, and should be marking the employee as no longer employed. If you're doing to delete a row that is referenced as a foreign key by another table, you need to delete those other rows too. Not doing so would make the foreign key meaningless and ruin any (and all) referential integrity you had.

Comment: Also, that DDL strongly implies you're storing plain text passwords; I really hope not. You should be using a has and salt to store passwords.

Comment: Deleting the employee while there is a reference to him in another table is making your database corrupt. You should add a datefield to your employee where you can mark him as not working here anymore from that date, in stead of deleting

Comment: Unless this employee is not used in any other table, then you can still delete him off course

Comment: I am going to make an 'unemployed' column, so instead of the employee being removed they will be classed as unemployed. I am using a hashing algorithm for the passwords. Thanks.

Comment: You can't delete the candidate/primary key while there are foreign keys referencing it. That's the whole point of Referential Integrity. Maybe what you need is a mapping table. Add an Employees.EmployeeID column as PK, add a table EmployeeBookingMap (EmployeeID, ClockNo), and move the Bookings.ClockNo foreign key to that. When you need to delete an Employee you update the EmployeeBookingMap.EmployeeID value to a "garbage collector" EmployeeID allowing you to delete the record of the Employee that's leaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach would be to have a flag in the Employee table as `isDeleted` and use that flag to maintain deleted employees. That way you will have records of all the orders of the deleted employees as well